# ARPACK error, Maximum number of iterations reached

Tags: r, igraph, eigenvector

I am using R and running leading eigenvector community detection algorithm.

`comm[2,]=c(membership(leading.eigenvector.community(g,options=list(maxiter=30120),weight=E(g)$weight)),max(leading.eigenvector.community(g,weight=E(g)$weight)$modularity))`

When I comment this line my graph plots correctly for some attributes and fails for some but uncommenting this line leads to the following error:

> At arpack.c:776 :ARPACK solver failed to converge (30120001 iterations, 0/1 eigenvectors converged)

I have tried increasing/decreasing the max number of iterations but still doesn't work.

Comment: There are some suggestions [here](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/512) for troubleshooting (got there by googling your error message)

Comment: Thanks Ben. But I have already tried them all before posting my question here. Nothing worked for me.

Comment: Then you're probably out of luck ...